# '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, while-loop

Python baby is stuck in the code. I know its childish thing but you know error is error I have no option instead to put it.

```
count=0,
    while(count<5):
        count=count+1
        count
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Why do you have a comma there next to `count=0`?

Comment: `0,`  means `count=(0,)` which is a completely different thing from `count=0`.

Answer (score -1):

First, you don't need comma next to count 0

Second, if you need to print count put print(count) instead of just count

Comment: "First, you ~~don't need~~ _must not put_ comma next to count 0"

Comment: Thanks for All of you. @Ash Duffy Zac